# Show Size of list visual force

Tags: visualforce, list, size

This is my VF page:

```
<apex:page standardController="Account">
<apex:relatedList list="Contacts" />
</apex:page>
```

I would like to show number of records in the related list.
I´ve tried, without success, with:

```
{!Account.Contacts.size}
```

How can i accomplish this?

***UPDATE***:
I know that i can do it in a controller extension (query contacts + size on result list) but i would like to calculate the number of record directly in the  VF page.

Thanks in adavantage for any advice

Comment: Workaround: you could add a custom numeric field to Contacts that always displays "1" and then do a roll up summary on the account object of that field on Contacts.

Comment: Thanks Tonino but using a roll up is a quite heavy solution. It will be better to count  number of records in the controller with a query, but i would like to calculate the number directly in the VF page.

Comment: Ok..I think maybe this is not possibile (in VF page).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is very simple. You can try this code. I tested, it is working:

You need to use `apex:repeat` tag to get count

```
<apex:page standardController="Account">
    <apex:variable var="count" value="{!0}"/>
    <apex:repeat value="{!Account.contacts}">
        <apex:variable var="count" value="{!count + 1}"/>
    </apex:repeat>
    size is {!count}
    <apex:relatedList list="Contacts" />
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a nasty workaround that works in later API versions.

It works by coercing the related items to a string and measuring the length.

(Note that standard controller **related items** are *not* just **SObject lists**... so treat as black box)

[image: count-related-list-items]

- Note [mysteries of VisualForceArrayList](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/28913/320)
- Note [reassigning variables in apex:repeat is officially unsupported](https://www.ca-peterson.com/2012/01/18/apex_repeat_indexes_in_visualforce_pages/)

Comment: Works as expected and cool

Answer (score -2):

I know it's been years since this question has been asked. But I think it could help others if I answer it anyway.

Use **`length`** instead of `size` in your markup.

```
{!Account.Contacts.length}
```