# Hide the <apex:Pageblock section

Tags: visualforce

EDIT:
I'm looking a way where it validates the condition and then it render the rest of the block? do VF provide something like this? for an example:

```
If myCollection > 0 then render this block of code?
```

I have tried few different way but I still see the block of empty space as shown in the pic. I would like to hide completely and only show when the `selectedContacts > 0`

here is my visualforce page code

```
<div align="center" style="padding:10px;" rendered="{!IF(SelectedContacts != NULL && SelectedContacts.size > 0, TRUE, FALSE)}">
    <apex:pageblock id="Selected_PBS" Title="{!IF(SelectedContacts != NULL && SelectedContacts.size > 0,'Selected Contact','There are no records selected')}"   >   

        <apex:pageMessages id="showmsg"></apex:pageMessages>
        <apex:pageBlockButtons rendered="{!IF(SelectedContacts != NULL && SelectedContacts.size > 0, TRUE, FALSE)}" >

              <apex:commandButton value="Add to Work Order!" action="{!addToWO}" rerender="showmsg"
                      disabled="{!If(selectedContacts != null && selectedContacts.size > 0,false, true)}" />
              <apex:commandButton style="left:30px;position:relative;" value="Clear" action="{!clear}" rerender="Selected_PBS"   />

        </apex:pageBlockButtons>
        <apex:pageBlockTable id="selected_contacts"   value="{!SelectedContacts}" var="contact"  rendered="{!IF(SelectedContacts != NULL && SelectedContacts.size > 0,true,false)}">
             <apex:column value="{!contact.Name}" style="width:25%" />
             <apex:column value="{!contact.Email}" style="width:25%" />
             <apex:column value="{!contact.Phone}" style="width:25%" />
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlock>    
    </div>
```

[image]

Comment: n.b. the IF, TRUE, FALSE are all unnecessary -- you only need to define the `condition` as that returns either true or false which is what rendered= cares about.  Also, testing for list null and size is tricky in VF if using StandardSetController which I'm guessing you are not using; added here for the next poor soul, see http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/28913/visualforcearraylist-mysteries-of-the-size-and-empty-properties

Comment: i usually wrap all my page block sections in output Panels and render them that way, most of these answers are junk.. @Eric looks like he's on the right path

Answer (score 1):

Rendered only works on apex tags/components

change

```
<div align="center" style="padding:10px;" rendered="{!IF(SelectedContacts != NULL && SelectedContacts.size > 0, TRUE, FALSE)}">
```

to

```
<apex:outPutPanel layout="block" style="text-align: center; padding:10px;" rendered="{!SelectedContacts.size > 0}">
```

Comment: does not do anything... still the same as it was before, I'm still learning VF but I'm looking a way where it validates the condition and then it render the rest of the block? do VF provide something like this?

Comment: @AbuHamzah - Apologies, the != null was causing it to appear even if it was empty. As for you last question, yes VF does that. Current answer deals with initial rendering only and not partial page refreshes

Comment: it throwing me this error if i remove the `null`, the error is  `The value 'null' is not valid for operator '>'
Error is in expression '{!SelectedContacts.size > 0} ' in component <apex:outputPanel>`

Comment: Then in your controller instantiate the List as an empty list in the constructor....

Comment: I'm instantiating `selectedContacts = new List<Contact>();` but still does not work.

Comment: Then something else is going on. Maybe show your controller and more go the vf page?

Answer (score 0):

```
<div align="center" style="padding:10px;" >
    <apex:pageblock Title="There are no records selected" rendered="{!IF(SelectedContacts != NULL && SelectedContacts.size > 0, FALSE, TRUE)}"">
    </apex:pageblock>
    <apex:pageblock id="Selected_PBS" Title="Selected Contact" rendered="{!IF(SelectedContacts != NULL && SelectedContacts.size > 0, TRUE, FALSE)}"">   

        <apex:pageMessages id="showmsg"></apex:pageMessages>
        <apex:pageBlockButtons>

              <apex:commandButton value="Add to Work Order!" action="{!addToWO}" rerender="showmsg" />
              <apex:commandButton style="left:30px;position:relative;" value="Clear" action="{!clear}" rerender="Selected_PBS"   />

        </apex:pageBlockButtons>
        <apex:pageBlockTable id="selected_contacts"   value="{!SelectedContacts}" var="contact" >
             <apex:column value="{!contact.Name}" style="width:25%" />
             <apex:column value="{!contact.Email}" style="width:25%" />
             <apex:column value="{!contact.Phone}" style="width:25%" />
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlock>    
    </div>
```

Comment: i have updated my question, did not work

Answer (score 0):

You can use Some thing like this you can use two output pannels and add the below conditions

```
<apex:outputPanel id="test1" style="display:{!if(SelectedContacts.size>0,'','none')}">
   <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!flag}">


<apex:outputPanel id="test2" style="display:{!if(SelectedContacts.size>0,'none','')}">
  <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!flag}">
```

here flag is the boolean condition which you can use according to your need from the controller.

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve this in the below way :

```
    <style>
 .divStyle{
    padding:10px;
 }
</style>
<apex:pageMessages id="showmsg"></apex:pageMessages>
<apex:outputPanel align="center" styleClass="divStyle" rendered="{!SelectedContacts.size > 0}">
    <apex:pageblock id="Selected_PBS" Title="{!IF(SelectedContacts != NULL && SelectedContacts.size > 0,'Selected Contact','There are no records selected')}"   >   


        <apex:pageBlockButtons >

              <apex:commandButton value="Add to Work Order!" action="{!addToWO}" rerender="showmsg"/>
              <apex:commandButton style="left:30px;position:relative;" value="Clear" action="{!clear}" rerender="Selected_PBS"/>

        </apex:pageBlockButtons>
        <apex:pageBlockTable id="selected_contacts"   value="{!SelectedContacts}" var="contact">
             <apex:column value="{!contact.Name}" style="width:25%" />
             <apex:column value="{!contact.Email}" style="width:25%" />
             <apex:column value="{!contact.Phone}" style="width:25%" />
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlock>   

</apex:outputPanel>
<apex:outputPanel align="center" styleClass="divStyle" rendered="{!NOT(SelectedContacts.size > 0)}">
    <apex:pageblock >   
            There are nothing to show.
    </apex:pageBlock>   

</apex:outputPanel>
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Stop just posting code, explain the code, If i don't understand apex and vf I would have no idea what your saying.

Comment: this is a problem regarding the syntax, that's why it is required to correct the syntax.From the question it seems like User is vey well aware of vf.