# getting list size

Tags: apex, soql, query, size

Please help - I want to count the list size so I will only render it in Visualforce page if > 0.
My error is:Variable does not exist: getCasesInApproval at line 15 column 18
Vairable does not exist? I don't get - I just made a list.
My Code:

```
public class MyConnectivityCasesSales {


    public MyConnectivityCasesSales(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {

    }




   public List <Case> getCasesInApproval (){ 
       return [select subject, CaseNumber, Contact.name, owner.name, Reason, Account.name, Status, Approval_Status__c, LastModifiedDate   from Case where Salesperson__c =:userinfo.getuserId() and isClosed !=TRUE ];
    }

  Integer size = getCasesInApproval.size();



}
```

Comment: getCasesInApproval isn't a List in scope, it's the name of a method...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can directly check the size in your visualforce page as follows

```
<apex:page controller="MyConnectivityCasesSales">
<apex:form>
<apex:outputpanel rendered="{!CasesInApproval.size!=0}">
<!-- Show only if size is greater than 0 -->
</apex:outputpanel>

</apex:form

</apex:page>
```

Comment: for a related discussion, see http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/28914/2602

Answer (score 2):

When referencing a list in Visualforce you can directly access the size using the syntax `{!myList.size}`. You could then create a boolean statement in Visualforce with `rendered="{!myList.size > 0}"`. Note that size is a property and not a function in Visualforce.