# Get Related list record Count

Tags: visualforce, related-list

Apart from **Roll-up summary fields** , is there any tag to get the  count of number of records in a related list?

I suppose we cannot use it like this :

```
Opportunitycount = Select OpportunityCount__c from Account WHERE id =:selectedaccountId;
```

I have an Dropdown of list of Accounts in the org and want to get the value of opportunity/case record count associated with that account upon selection from page.

Comment: have you tried `SELECT count() FROM Opportunity WHERE AccountId = 'something'` ?

Comment: Yep...aggregate SOQL can do this really well. Or querying child relationships from the parent and using `List.size()` to find the child record count. `SELECT Id, (Id from Child_Relationships__r) from Parent_Object__c`. @Ratan if you don't write up an answer, I will. ;-)

Comment: check out http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/17429/2602