# How should I check whether the map is empty or not in Visualforce page (API version 38.0)

Tags: visualforce, map, rendered

I am displaying some records in table format on my `Visualforce Page`. I want to check if a `Map` instance is empty before displaying it. I have tried with:

```
.Size()
```

and also with:

```
rendered="{!If(NOT(ISBLANK(cons[0])),true,false)}"
```

But it is not working. I know one workaround to use a `Boolean` property in the controller and set the `rendered` attribute based on that. But I don't want to create extra variables in the controller. Can we achieve this logical check in the `Visualforce Page` itself?

Comment: With `rendered="{!NOT(ISBLANK(cons[0]))}"` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to test list size from a VisualForce page?](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/17429/is-it-possible-to-test-list-size-from-a-visualforce-page)

Comment: I think whilst the "solution" is the same, the difference in the wording and context of the question means this might be a valid question/answer as would be expected to find in a search. People looking to find if a "map is empty" in visualforce might not search for "how to test a list size" ? (just my thoughts)

Comment: Just because we close as a dupe doesn't mean it's a bad question! But it helps link them as essentially the same issue, which I think they are here. And it doesn't at all hurt the search-ability of this question. If it did, I'd probably reconsider my vote.

Comment: @AdrianLarson while it should be a dupe, since maps and lists SHOULD work the same, unfortunately they don't; using `map.size` as would work on a list, comes up with a compile time error.

Answer (score 9):

The below solution **does not work** reporting this compile error when the page is saved:

> Unknown property 'cons.size'

If `cons` is a map field of the controller, I would expect this to work:

```
rendered="{! cons.size > 0 }"
```

as a reference to `cons` is a reference to the map keys.

Comment: For Map , Size is not valid in visual force page . Thanks

Comment: @veera Just tried it and similar permutations and you are right... Looks like an extra controller property is needed.

Answer (score 5):

I have had success with this approach:

```
rendered="{!NOT(myMap.empty)}"
```

Note you can always replace `IF(condition, true, false)` with simply `condition`. The statements are functionally equivalent, but the former is redundant and bloats compile size.

Comment: It is not working for Map. Please suggest any other way to do. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you cannot directly reference the size of a Map in VF.  You can add a small helper to return the size, however:

```
public Integer mapSize {get{
    mapSize = mapVariable.values().size();
    return mapSize;
    }set;}
```

It is less convenient than getting the value directly on the VF but it works.